# How do I find a string in a file?

Tags: c

I'm new at C and recently finished my work with files. I tried to create a program which will find an entered name in a file but it does not work. Could you try to repair it?  I'll be thankful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    int i,p,counter,final,length,j,c,k = 0;
    char name[256];
    char buffer[1024];

    fr = fopen("C:/Users/prixi/Desktop/HESLA.TXT","r");
    while ((c = fgetc(fr)) != EOF)
        counter++;

    printf("Enter the name");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    length = strlen(name);

    while (fscanf(fr, " %1023[^\n]", buffer) != EOF) {
        for (i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
            if (name[0] == buffer[i]){
                for (j = 0;j < length; j++ )
                    if (name[j] == buffer[i+j])
                        p++;
                    else
                        p = 0;

              /* The 2nd condition is there because after every name there is ' '. */
              if (p == length && buffer[i+j+1] == ' ')
                  final = 1;
          }
     }

     if ( final == 1 )
         printf("its there");
     else
         printf("its not there"); 
return 0;
}
```

It loads the inside of the file to the buffer and then scans char by char depending on how long the file is. I know that it's inefficient and slow, but I have been learning C only for like 4 days. I would really like you to help me fixing my own code otherwise :D I probably wont be able to fall asleep.

Comment: Learn to use a *debugger!* Set breakpoints, single-step through the code, inspect variables. Where are the variables (or the program flow) not as you would expect?

Comment: well i tried almost everything and tried to debug it but when i entered name which was also in that file it always wrote ITs not there i dont know where i made a mistake even now im trying to look for mistake i have made but when i go line by line in my code and try to imagine what it does it should work imo

Comment: Post the complete source code, parts are missing that are important.

Comment: edited the code it should be the whole code

Comment: You must be more careful to initialise flags such as `p` and `final` *before* you iterate and not *after*. `p` is undefined on the first usage, and `final` might be, as the compiler should have told you.

Comment: Agree with @Weather Vane.  Do you really want to only initialize `k` and not `i,p,counter,final,length,j,c`?

Comment: For future ref: "but it does not work" is nearly worthless. _Much_ better to describe input, what happened (output) and what was expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of way to search  a string into a File.
Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *loadFile(const char *fileName);

int main (void) {
    const char *fileName = "test.txt";
    const char *stringToSearch = "Addams";
    char *fileContent = loadFile(fileName);

    if (strstr(fileContent, stringToSearch)){
        printf("%s was Found\n",stringToSearch);
    }else{
        printf("%s was not Found\n",stringToSearch);
    }

    free(fileContent);

    return 0;
}

char *loadFile(const char *fileName){
    size_t length,size;
    char *buffer;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen (fileName , "r" );
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Error fopen, please check the file\t%s\n",fileName);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    length = (size_t)ftell (file);
    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET);

    buffer = malloc(length+1);
    if (buffer == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }

    size = fread (buffer,1,length,file);
    if (size != length){
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit(3);
    }
    buffer[length] = '\0';

    fclose (file);
    return buffer;
}
```

Output:

> Addams was Found

I have inside the file "test.txt" the following:

> ```
> Michael Jackson
> Bryan Addams
> Jack Sparrow
> ```

Comment: Small item: Why use `sizeof(char)` which is _always_ 1 in `malloc(sizeof(char)*(size_t)length)`.  Maybe `malloc((size_t)length)` or `malloc((size_t)length * sizeof *buffer)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.  You did not post the variable definitions, so we cannot verify if they are used consistently, especially `name` that should be an array of `char`.

The main issue is this: you count the number of bytes in `fr` by reading it, but you do not `rewind` the stream before scanning it for instances of the string.